# Finding a plane normal from homography of 2 images?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, augmented-reality, homography

I have 2 images taken from different angles and positions of a plane. I found 4 matching points and computed the homography matrix, H. This picture is showing the transform using it, so it is defiantly working

[image]

I now want to find the normal of this plane. In the book *An Invitation to 3-D Vision* It says you can decompose this to

[image]

where N is the normal of the plane. I have done this and the result I get a solution where

N =  [-0.00514723, 0.00503588, 0.99997407]

For other examples too this normal is just almost pointing strait up in the Z direction... What could cause this??

P.S. I also checked that reversing the above equation gave me H again and it does, so there are valid solutions but the plane is clearly far from strait up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula is correct. I suspect you are trying to apply it without using an intrinsic calibration of the camera (which is required). Do you have a camera intrinsic calibration? If so you should first convert the correspondences to 'normalized pixel coordinates' (in OpenCV you do this with undistortpoints), then you compute the homography between these normalized points, then decompose using the formula.